# Passive construction

Tags: passive-voice

Active Voice:

> I remember them taking me to the zoo.

My answers:

> 1. I remember being taken to the zoo.( this sentence doesn't make any sense to me)
> 2. They are remembered taking me to the zoo.( Because I think them is object of verb  remember)

i don't know why but both answer seems incorrect.

but there is another case where i take 'them taking me to the zoo' as a single unit object. then if we make passive it looks like Them taking to me the zoo is remembered by me. this is completely wrong.

I contradict myself. I am confused. what should be the Passive of given sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Sentence #1

> I remember being taken to the zoo.

This is correct and sounds very normal to native ears. **Being taken to the zoo** functions as a noun phrase denoting the act in which you were taken to the zoo. **Being** is a gerund here. The passive construction here omits the subject; the implied subject is **me** (which a person would only say in order to create unusually strong emphasis).

It might help to look at some comparable sentences where the subject of **being taken** is explicit:

> I remember John being taken to the zoo.
>
> I remember him being taken to the zoo.

Notice that the subject of **being taken** is in the objective case. That's because it's also the object of **remember**, the main verb of the sentence.

### Sorry, I have to tell you this

There's also an older school of thought that says the previous two sentences are incorrect and should instead be:

> I remember John's being taken to the zoo.
>
> I remember his being taken to the zoo.

In this parsing, the object of **remember** is **being taken to the zoo**. The subject of the gerund in this construction takes the possessive case (strangely enough).

Most fluent speakers today hear both **him being taken** and **his being taken** as correct. That is, people can parse both forms. The first form works by analogy with **I helped him learn** and the second form works by analogy with **I helped his education**.

### Sentence #2

> They are remembered taking me to the zoo.

This is actually correct, just a little unusual. Here, **taking** is a present participle, not a gerund. **Taking me to the zoo** modifies **they**, in the manner of a subject-complement. A comparable sentence might make this clearer:

> Football players are usually drawn running with the ball.

In other words, in most pictures of football players, the football player is running with the ball.

The reason your example sentence is unusual isn't because of the grammar, it's because it's a little hard to imagine a situation where people would be remembered that way. But it's certainly possible and the sentence can be understood. Perhaps someone took a photograph of "them" while they were taking you to the zoo, they died long ago, and since then, many people have seen this photograph.

Comment: I would rewrite sentence #1 as "I remember being taken to the zoo by them."

Comment: @mkennedy That's also how I'd put "I remember them taking me to the zoo" into the passive voice. However, by "Sentence #1" I meant the sentence with the number 1 in front of it in the question. I'm just explaining why the two numbered sentences are correct, not suggesting rewrites. Maybe that could be clearer.